# Loading image data from pandas dataframe with path and class label to PyTorch DataLoader?

Tags: pandas, keras, pytorch, torchvision, image-classification

I have a dataset of images that I'm looking to apply binary classification to using PyTorch. The training data is in the form of a csv file that has the image path and image label (0 or 1) as the columns of the csv[See below for csv format].

```
img_path,printer_id,print_id,has_under_extrusion
101/1678589738/1678589914.060332.jpg,101,1678589738,1
101/1678589738/1678589914.462857.jpg,101,1678589738,1
101/1678589738/1678589914.875075.jpg,101,1678589738,1
...
...
```

I filled a pandas Dataframe with this data using the .read_csv() function. I want to use the information in the Dataframe to fill a PyTorch `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and ultimately wrap it in a DataLoader while applying transforms to each of the images. I'm looking for something similar to Keras' implementation of the function `flow_from_dataframe()` Is there a function similar to this offered by PyTorch or would it require a new implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in pytorch there isn't samething like flow_from_dataframe. But you can define your own custom dataset easily like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image_path = self.data.img_path[index]
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        label = self.data.has_under_extrusion[index] #I guess this is your class
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, label

# Define transformations to apply to the images
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

# Create a PyTorch DataLoader object
dataset = MyDataset('my_data.csv', transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```